# Blender API: Intersection between 2 lines not working as expected

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to use the `mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_line` function to get the closest point between two lines, which is the expected behaviour according to the documentation. However I'm getting `None` as the result of the function:

```
wrist = bpy.context.scene.objects['Wrist']
segment1 = bpy.context.scene.objects['Segment1-1']

# Frame N_1 (Wrist)
frameN_1 = wrist.matrix_world
originFrameN_1 = mathutils.Vector((frameN_1.col[3][0:3]))
zaxisFrameN_1 = mathutils.Vector((frameN_1.col[2][0:3]))

# Frame N (Segment)
originFrameN = mathutils.Vector((segment1.matrix_world.col[3][0:3]))
zaxisFrameN = mathutils.Vector((segment1.matrix_world.col[2][0:3]))

P1 = originFrameN_1
P2 = originFrameN_1 + zaxisFrameN_1
P3 = originFrameN
P4 = originFrameN + zaxisFrameN

intersect = mathutils.geometry.intersect_line_line(P1,P2,P3,P3)
```

intersect returns None where I expect a tuple with the closest points between the lines created along Z axis of the two objects.

Comment: add your blender version , could be a bug ( tested on 2.77a and it returns None )

Comment: Version 2.77a as well.

Comment: if you have access to older version try to confirm it is a bug ( then file a bug report )

Comment: I'm getting same behaviour in version 2.69, so I'm going to report the bug. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a chance a) your two lines are parallel or b) that P1 = P2 or P3 = P4?

Comment: Best include the actual values and make a self contained script.